# Simple Equivalence About Jordan Measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $J \subset \mathbb{R^{n}}$ be a limited set.
It's really easy to prove that if J is Jordan measurable, then the content of its border is zero.

However, I would like to prove the converse. The suggestion on this exercise was to prove that if a rectangle R intersects both int(A) and ext(A), then it intersects also bd(A). I did this, no problem. Though I'm not seeing how it helps.

Im sorry if this question annoys anyone, but im starting just now studying Real Analysis.
Thank you for help :)

Comment: What is your definition of Jordan measurability? Which criteria do you have at hand?

Comment: I already solved this (or at least i think so), but thanks anyway. I just defined the content of elementary sets. Then, let U(X) be the class of elementary sets in X. Then the definition of Jordan Measurability that im learning, is the following : Let $J \subset \mathbb{R^{n}}$ be a limited set. Let $c_{\star}(J)$=sup$\lbrace c(K) : K\in U(J)\rbrace$ and let $c^{\star}(J)$=inf$\lbrace c(L) : L\in U(\mathbb{R^{n}}) \text{and} J\subset L\rbrace$, where c denotes the content of an elementary set. Then J is Jordan Measurable iff $c_{\star}(J)$=$c^{\star}(J)$.

Comment: Alright. A similar question already has good answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79778/how-to-prove-e-subset-rn-jordan-measurable-is-equivalent-to-bare-e-is-jo?rq=1.